# how to get remote service videos thumbnails for ios in appcelerator?

Tags: ios, json, video, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing  ios app in appcelerator studios .In that app i need to show  thumbnails of remote service videos . I am getting videos data through JSON object. I am getting thumbnails for only one video rest of them also i am getting but those are append to first video of the JSON object.
can any one help  me how to show thumbnails for remote located videos ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully get your question, but from your title I take that you want to generate thumbnails for remove videos?

For this you can use the following API:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.VideoPlayer-method-requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes

This does mean that you have to load in every single video (the view itself does not need to be visible to the user) which is quite heavy. So if at all possible it is better to get them from wherever you get the videos from, or use some middleware to generate and cache them there.